# Feynman diagrams for interacting theory of scalar field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

Is it correct that the number of lines originating from vertices on Feynman diagrams is equal to the order of phi in interaction lagrangian for scalar field?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Although it's probably informative for you to learn where the parts of a Feynman diagram come from.

Comment: Is the number of lines originating from vertices not equal to the order of phi in the interaction Lagrangian?

Comment: But what happens if one has a feynman diagram with 3- and 4-line vertices?

Comment: You won't have any such bare vertices, but if the amplitude of such a dressed vertex is non-zero, then you would have such vertices, but that would mean that your original Lagrangian acquires corrections and now contains new terms like $\phi^4$. I think.